# Css3 nth-child selector don't act the way expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am coming up to you guys cause i heared that instead of using javascript to select every 2 elements, you can use the nth-child css3 selector...

I attempted to use it but it didn't work the way i was expecting... And it makes no sense for me that it's not working...

Here is what i get when i use nth-child(odd) :

[image]

The first element is working well... the margin is working.
But instead of the third element having a margin, it's the fourth one that have it... And i don't really understand why this is happening...

Some code :

```html
<section id="portfolio">
    <ul>
        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/547404026266152.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details"><img id="portfolio-logo" src="http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo-v2-slogan.png"></div>
        </li>

        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/a_Hamburger-Bun-with-HamburgerS_3.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details"><img id="portfolio-logo" src=""></div>
        </li>

        <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
            <div id="portfolio-selected"></div>
        </li>

        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/24346_l.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details"><img id="portfolio-logo" src=""></div>
        </li>

        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/unnamed-1.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details"><img id="portfolio-logo" src=""></div>
        </li>

        <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
            <div id="portfolio-selected"></div>
        </li>

        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/maximoto.png);">
            <div id="portfolio-details"><img id="portfolio-logo" src="http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/maxi1.png"></div>
        </li>

        <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
            <div id="portfolio-selected"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

and the CSS :

```css
#portfolio {
    width:100%;
    margin:40px 0 0
}

#portfolio ul {
    list-style:none
}

#portfolio ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    height:300px;
    width:470px;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
    filter:grayscale(100%);
    transition:all .2s linear
}

.single-portfolio:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-right:26px
}

#portfolio ul li:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
    filter:grayscale(0%)
}

#portfolio-details {
    background:rgba(150,150,150,0.7);
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    transition:all .2s linear;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative
}

#portfolio-details img {
    transition:all .2s linear;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    max-width:300px
}

#portfolio-details:hover {
    background:rgba(26,188,156,0);
    width:100%;
    height:100%
}

#portfolio-details:hover img {
    opacity:0
}
```

if you guys could help me and explain me what's wrong... Would be amazing !

Thanks in advance

Comment: since margin is not respected by inline elements, your image looks like i expect.

Comment: why would you make the li display inline and not inline-block?

Comment: it should be _display:list-item_, with _list-style:none_ if you don't want bullets

Comment: The li is inline-block... What's wrong from that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `<div id="portfolio-selected"></div>` is coming between the lists, so `nth-child()` won't work. Use `nth-of-type()` instead:

```
.single-portfolio:nth-of-type(odd) {...}
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".single-portfolio").eq(0).addClass('green')
```

```css
.single-portfolio:nth-of-type(odd) {color:red}

.green{color:green;}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio">
    <ul>
        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/547404026266152.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details">
                <img id="portfolio-logo" src="http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/logo-v2-slogan.png">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/a_Hamburger-Bun-with-HamburgerS_3.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details">
                <img id="portfolio-logo" src=""/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <div id="portfolio-selected"></div>
        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/24346_l.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details">
                <img id="portfolio-logo" src=""/>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/unnamed-1.jpg);">
            <div id="portfolio-details">
                <img id="portfolio-logo" src="">
            </div>
        </li>
        <div id="portfolio-selected"></div>
        <li class="single-portfolio" style="background-image: url(http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/maximoto.png);">
            <div id="portfolio-details">
                <img id="portfolio-logo" src="http://localhost/robeenNew/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/maxi1.png">
            </div>
        </li>
        <div id="portfolio-selected"></div>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working correctly to me.

Your PHP is rendering empty elements. That's what confusing you.

If the empty elements are desired, maybe you should give them a different class.  Or use a second class on the non-empty elements just for this CSS treatment.

EDIT:

My suggestion above won't work.  [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). The `nth-child` only cares about how many siblings the matched element has. It doesn't filter them.

You'll need to use your PHP to add `.odd` classes to the elements you want to style, or else change your markup in some drastic way to give the CSS a handle to the odd elements.

Comment: The empty li elements are desired... By the way, the nth-child is on the .single-portfolio so the empty li elements should not bother that....

Comment: The `.single-portfolio` class isn't a filter, it's a _selector_.  That's the important difference.

Comment: You're selecting all `.single-portfolio` elements which are the odd child of their parent. I think that's what you're having trouble with.

Comment: @robben issue is with psuedo selector  not with empty lists, see my answer